# Bootstrap 3.0 Removing Double Tap on Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm moving from Bootstrap 2.3 to Bootstrap 3.0 and want to remove the double tap functionality from the li elements in a dropdown in a navbar.

So for example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the above I don't want to have to double tap to select the Action line link.

I have tried restructuring my anchors, but it appears to be tied to the class name.  I suspect I will have to modify the bootstrap js file, and this isn't an issue.  Just can't figure out which I have to edit.

Does anyone know if this will be possible?

Comment: can you add a jsFiddle?

Comment: can someone explain what "double tap" refers to?

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake.  There is no double tap style functionality with Bootstrap.  Instead what was happening was that since I was hiding child elements (display: none) the dropdown still thought they existed.  Normally you would tab once to display the dropdown, and then tap again to access the parent.  By completely removing the hidden child elements the dropdown functioned with a single tap.